# Constant spacing between baselines for matplotlib multiline text with special characters

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting

I have some multiline text with special characters (not within the basic Latin Unicode block) that I want to put on an axis with `ax.text`, but some lines render taller than others, and I would like to keep the line height constant. I have tried the `linespacing` keyword, but this just seems to put a constant amount of space between each line.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

text_props = {'va':'top', 'fontsize':20}

# linespacing=1
ax.text(.1,1,'small line\nsmall line\nĢĀ\nĢĀ\nsmall line\nsmall line', ha='left', linespacing=1, **text_props)
ax.text(.1,1,'10\n20\n30\n40\n50\n60', ha='right', c='r', linespacing=1, **text_props)

# linespacing=2
ax.text(.6,1,'small line\nsmall line\nĢĀ\nĢĀ\nsmall line\nsmall line', ha='left',  linespacing=2,  **text_props)
ax.text(.6,1,'10\n20\n30\n40\n50\n60', ha='right', c='r', linespacing=2, **text_props)
```

I am almost certain the problem is the special charaters `Ģ` and `Ā`, which change the "bottom" and "top" of the lines. This same problem is with different fonts, not only the default one.

[image: A plot of the unit square showing different renderings of text, made with Python matplotlib]

I know that there is the option `va='baseline'`, so I could make a function that splits a big block of text line by line, but I'm wondering if there is something is simpler, like an option `lineheight=20` or `baselinespacing=20`(I know these doesn't exist), so I can specify only one anchor point for the whole block of text.

So, my question is: **How can I make the distance between one baseline and the next always be the same, irrespective of the text and the number of lines?**